# Testing my anaphora resolution tool

Tags: testing, resolution

I am in the course of building an anaphora resolution tool. I have done a lot of literature review and I have a pretty good idea on what I should do to build a basic tool. However, the problem is, how do I test it. I can't find any annotated corpus which I could test it on. Could someone suggest how I would measure the precision and recall of my tool.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about linguistics.

Answer (score 1):

From here:
http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/COLI_a_00152

Section 4.1
OntoNotes-Dev
– development partition of OntoNotes v4.0 provided in
the CoNLL2011 shared task (Pradhan et al. 2011).
OntoNotes-Test
– test partition of OntoNotes v4.0 provided in the
CoNLL-2011 shared task.
ACE2004-Culotta-Test
– partition of the ACE 2004 corpus reserved for
testing by several previous studies (Culotta et al. 2007; Bengtson and Roth
2008; Haghighi and Klein 2009).
ACE2004-nwire
– newswire subset of the ACE 2004 corpus, utilized by
Poon and Domingos (2008) and Haghighi and Klein (2009) for testing.
MUC6-Test
– test corpus from the sixth Message Understanding
Conference (MUC-6) evaluation.

You can find MUC details here 
http://www-nlpir.nist.gov/related_projects/muc/muc_data/muc_data_index.html

Just look around at the start of the experimental section in your references. You are bound to find links. If you look at the most commonly used ones, you will find your data sets.